# NGINX Caching: behave as private cache

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm trying to setup NGINX as an HTTP cache in front of a webserver and found this great guide: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/.

The default behavior is that NGINX won't cache any responses with `Cache-Control: private` and you can completely disable this behavior using `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control`, but is there a middle ground where NGINX will behave as a private browser cache? I want it to cache `private` respones and still abide by the `max-age` directives.